# Rake:task equivalent in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, rake

I have a django application where i'll like to have a script that i'll run once a day to validate the models in the database, and delete some objects. How cand i make it ? I want something equivalent to rake:task in rails.

Answer (score 12):

Also look at [setting up a custom subcommand for your manage.py](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this: [django-tasks](http://code.google.com/p/django-tasks/)

Answer (score 2):

May be [celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/) would be better in this case.

Because as stated in django-tasks page:

> Django-tasks is for a different usage
>   from most other tasks frameworks
>   (Celery, Cue...): this is not for
>   numerous, quick, light, tasks, but for
>   few, long, heavy, tasks. Typical usage
>   is to batch process data for each
>   model object, and give information
>   about the processing to the user.

So it depends on the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is more commonly used for application deployment and system administration, [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) might be interesting.